# d3 line chart data point is cropped from min and max domain values

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

i am working on d3 charts with react and new on both react and d3. The issue i am trying to solve is;
I have a line chart and i have useInteractiveGuideline enabled, so when i hover over the graph, i can see what my value is on that point(with a circle on the line). The problem is; for the y axis values that are close to min or max grid lines, the data point is cropped just from the edge domain values and becomes an half circle.
[line chart with cropped data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQe4k.png)

I need some sort of padding to see the whole point on edges.
Is there any way to do that other than changing the domain values? I don't wanna change the domain values since my data is dynamic and can reach to very big numbers, so it may not be stable.

```
    nv.addGraph(() => {
        let chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .padData(true)
            .noData('')
            .margin({ "top": 20, "right": 20, "bottom": 20, "left": 20 })
            .yDomain([0, max])
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

        chart.xAxis
            .showMaxMin(false)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickFormat((d) => {
                return ticks[d]
            })

        chart.yAxis.tickFormat((d) => {
            return d;
        })

        d3.select('#chart')
            .datum(chartData)
            .transition().duration(700)
            .call(chart);

        return chart;
    });
```

Comment: Solution is turned out to be really simple. I've added this line and issue is solved;
chart.lines.clipEdge(false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added below line and issue is solved

```
chart.lines.clipEdge(false);
```